# SHA2 password storage with Java

Tags: java, security, encryption, xml-rpc, jasypt

I'm attempting to make a XML-RPC call that requires HmacSHA-256 hashing of a particular string.  I'm currently using the Jasypt library with the following code:

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptor sha256 = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
          sha256.setPassword(key);
          sha256.setAlgorithm("PBEWithHmacSHA2");
```

On trying to use sha256.encrypt(string) I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithHmacAndSHA256 SecretKeyFactory not available
     at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:597)
     at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:488)
     at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.encrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:541)
     at nysenateapi.XmlRpc.main(XmlRpc.java:52)
    Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithHmacAndSHA256 SecretKeyFactory not available
     at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.(DashoA13*..)
     at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
     at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:584)
     ... 3 more
```

I downloaded the JCE Cryptography extension and placed the jars in my buildpath, but that doesn't seem to have done anything.  I've tried using a number of combinations in setAlgorithm above, including "PBE", "PBEWithSha"(1|2|128|256)?, "PBEWithHmacSha", etc.

I also tried using BouncyCastle but I didn't have any luck there either.  Any help or guidance appreciated!

Comment: a message digest function is not an encryption function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly noted by @Rook you need to specify a PBE algorithm that includes an *encryption* algorithm. Two examples out of many are `"PBEWithSHA1AndDESede"` which is supported by the [SunJCE provider](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJCEProvider) and `"PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC"` which is supported by the Bouncycastle JCE provider.

Answer (score 1):

The comments were helpful but I guess I was asking the wrong question.  What I was looking to do was mimic the PHP function hash_hmac('sha256',string,key)...

I ended up using the following code:

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSha256");
SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "HmacSha256");
mac.init(secret);
byte[] shaDigest = mac.doFinal(phrase.getBytes());
String hash = "";
for(byte b:shaDigest) {
    hash += String.format("%02x",b);
}
```

Thanks for the guidance, though.  Will surely help me in the future.

Comment: If `phrase` is a string you should consider specifying an encoding in getBytes() otherwise you might lose information when non-ascii text is hashed. (In order to be compatible with PHP I think it depends on `mb_internal_encoding()` of the PHP installation/request). The most usefull might be UTF-8 as it will be accent sensitive.